# Optimizing Multi-Filtering Using LINQ-To-Entities

Tags: c#, linq

I am making a c# application where I filter items on a data grid view using multiple combobox, each combobox has "All" at the top of its list where if selected it will not apply the filter in the DGV items. I have written the code but when applying 2 filters at once the query is slow a bit, I have not made the rest of the filters until I know that the method I am using is optimal or not.

```
namespace HDA_InfoBook
{
    public partial class frmGallery : Form
    {
        HDAEntities HDA = new HDAEntities();
        IQueryable<Hero> firstQuery = null;
        IQueryable<Hero> finalQuery = null;

        public frmGallery()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ViewResults(IQueryable<Hero> viewResult)
        {
            var gridSource = from r in viewResult
                             select new
                             {
                                 Name   = r.Name,
                                 Rarity = r.Rarity,
                                 Speed  = r.Speed,
                                 Attack = r.Attack,
                                 Target = r.Target
                             };
            dgdResult.DataSource = gridSource.ToList();
        }

        public void InitializeQuery()
        {
            firstQuery = from hero in HDA.CharactersNames
                         orderby hero.HeroRarity
                         select new Hero
                         {
                             ID       = hero.ID,
                             Name     = hero.HeroName,
                             RarityID = hero.HeroRarity,
                             Rarity   = hero.Rarity.RarityName,
                             Speed    = hero.Initiative,
                             Attack   = hero.Attack,
                             Target   = hero.Attack2.Description
                         };
            ViewResults(firstQuery);
        }

        public void ReloadAll()
        {
            finalQuery = firstQuery;
        }

        public void FilterRarity(int rarityId)
        {
                finalQuery = from o in finalQuery
                            where o.RarityID == rarityId
                            select new Hero
                            {
                                ID       = o.ID,
                                Name     = o.Name,
                                RarityID = o.RarityID,
                                Rarity   = o.Rarity,
                                Speed    = o.Speed,
                                Attack   = o.Attack,
                                Target   = o.Target
                            };
        }

        public void FilterGroup(int groupId)
        {

                var subQuery = from hero in HDA.Hero_Group
                               where hero.GroupID == groupId
                               select hero.HeroID;

                finalQuery = from o in finalQuery
                             where subQuery.Contains(o.ID)
                             select new Hero
                             {
                                 ID       = o.ID,
                                 Name     = o.Name,
                                 RarityID = o.RarityID,
                                 Rarity   = o.Rarity,
                                 Speed    = o.Speed,
                                 Attack   = o.Attack,
                                 Target   = o.Target
                             };
        }

        public void ApplyFilter()
        {
            ReloadAll();
            if (cboRarity.SelectedIndex != 0)
                FilterRarity(cboRarity.SelectedIndex);
            if (cboGroup.SelectedIndex != 0/*-1 && cboGroup.ValueMember != ""*/)
                FilterGroup((byte)cboGroup.SelectedValue);
                //FilterGroup(cboGroup.SelectedIndex);
            ViewResults(finalQuery);
        }

        private void cboRarity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplyFilter();
        }

        private void cboGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ApplyFilter();
        }
    }
}
```

## Update

This frustrating, when I applied a third filter the query time dramatically decreases, why is that ?

## Update 2

This is working much faster

```
    public void ApplyFilter2()
    {
        var subQuery = from hero in HDA.Hero_Group
                            where hero.GroupID == ((byte)cboGroup.SelectedValue)
                            select hero.HeroID;

        var q = from o in HDA.CharactersNames
                select new
                {
                    ID = o.ID,
                    Name = o.HeroName,
                    RarityID = o.HeroRarity,
                    Rarity = o.Rarity.RarityName,
                    Speed = o.Initiative,
                    Attack = o.Attack,
                    Target = o.Attack2.Description
                };
        if (cboRarity.SelectedIndex != 0)
            q = q.Where(o => o.RarityID == cboRarity.SelectedIndex);
        if (cboGroup.SelectedIndex != 0)
            q = q.Where(o => subQuery.Contains(o.ID));
        if (cboSpeed.SelectedIndex != 0)
            q = q.Where(o => o.Speed == cboSpeed.SelectedIndex);
        dgdResult.DataSource = q.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I would avoid the use of an instance field here.  Have each of the "apply filter" method accept an `IQueryable` and return an `IQueryable` rather than having them all mutate an instance field.  It will make the program much easier to reason about.  In general though, try it, and see if it works, rather than asking us if it works or not.

Comment: Also, you're constantly selecting out all of the fields each time you add a filter.  That's rather pointless.  It's not wrong, but it's wasted effort.  Only one line in `FilterRarity` is actually doing anything useful.

Comment: @Servy Could you elaborate how could I use IQueryable, please, if you don't mind ?

Comment: The way you are doing it is quite good. For each filter configuration you produce a specialized query so that SQL Server can optimally use indexes. The problem is probably on the SQL Server side. Your indexing strategy might be insufficient. Inform us about your schema. You can test my theory by applying indexes for every field mindlessly and seeing whether that helped.

Comment: @usr I am using `dbo` schema in my SQL server tables

Comment: @Tima You're already using `IQueryable`, your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @usr It seems the slow query is due to the data my query holds; I reduced the data to only the Name and I have the query speed significantly increased. Now, I don't know what to do to view the other data ???

Comment: @Tima by schema I meant your table structure and indexes. As I said you should research how to do index tuning. Do you understand that this is a database performance problem and that you cannot do anything in C# to make this faster?

Comment: @usr I see, thanks for explaining that. And by the way I have tried method chaining to make the query where to be dynamic and it was very much faster. I will update my thread with the new code so others can see it. Thanks.

Comment: Your updated code is basically the same as your older code, you just removed a lot of the needless fluff that wasn't actually helping (such as, as I said earlier, the constant projecting of each value out to the same type with the same content).  It's a whole lot less code, but it should do exactly the same thing as before.